# Generate a random string from another string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to input a string `"abcde12345ABCDE"` using scanner and then generate a random string of length 4 with the following requirements:

- 1st place it should be a character
- 2nd place it should be a number
- 3rd place it should be a number
- at 4th place it should also be character

Example run:

```
Input 
abcde12345ABCDE

\\Processing....
Output
A25b
```

Then I also want to be prompted to match the generated number.

```
Plz enter the generated no.!!
A25b
```

---

Here is the code I have used to generate a random string

```
final String alphanumeric = "abcde12345ABCDE";
final int n = alphanumeric.length();
Random r = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
    System.out.println(alphanumeric.charAt(r.nextInt(n)));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question - the example you gave is quite confusing. Also, please share the code you have you tried already in order to solve this, and indicate where you are having the problem.

Comment: Final string ="abcde12345ABCDE";  final int n=alphanumeric. Length(); random r=new random(); for(int i=0;i<4;i++) { System.out.println(alphanumeric. Charar(r.nextint(n)));}}}...

Comment: It's output is aBe1..... But i want its output should be a25D means at first place it should me letter, at second and third place it should be number and at forth place it should be letter .......and after that confirm the generated number like password confirm

Comment: @Chris - Are these edits clear enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String alphanumeric = "abcde12345ABCDE";
    List<Character> digits = getPart(alphanumeric, true);
    List<Character> letters = getPart(alphanumeric, false);

    Random r = new Random();
    System.out.print(letters.get(r.nextInt(letters.size())));
    System.out.print(digits.get(r.nextInt(digits.size())));
    System.out.print(digits.get(r.nextInt(digits.size())));
    System.out.print(letters.get(r.nextInt(letters.size())));
}

public static List<Character> getPart(String src, boolean numbers) {
    List<Character> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < src.length(); i++) {
        if (numbers == Character.isDigit(src.charAt(i))) {
            result.add(src.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```